# How to post an edge with Gremlin using node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, gremlin, amazon-neptune

I am trying to add an edge and in my tests, I am getting a 201 error. However, when I query the new edge in the console, I am unable to see the new edge.

````
    .hasLabel('Supplied_Material')
    .hasId(supld_matl_id)
    .as('sm')
    .V()
    .hasLabel('Capacity_Type')
    .hasId(capacity_type_cd)
    .coalesce(_.inE('uses_captype'), _.addE('uses_captype').from_('sm')
      .property(gremlin.process.t.id, `TEST|${supld_matl_id}:${matl_size_cd}:${production_step}:${capacity_priority}->${capacity_type_cd}`)
      .property('division_cd', division_cd)```
````

Comment: In your example I do not see an iterate() step at the end. Are you submitting this query as text to the HTTP endpoint or using the gremlin-javascript client library? I assume you are sending this as text noting the triple quotes at the end but wanted to check first before digging deeper. One sidenote - checking the label type before an ID lookup may be redundant as IDs are unique.

Comment: As it turns out, this was working the whole time. We had to change the logic to account for multiple edges between two nodes. Thank you so much for your response. Your book has been incredibly helpful. Also my team are big fans!

Comment: Also try adding id() to the end of your query to see what Edge ID you get back.

Comment: Great to hear and thanks for the kind words :-)

Comment: @KelvinLawrence is there a reference for the language variants? I am having trouble finding all of the javascript changes? I would love to help create something if not.